# Solve Integer division in floating point context

Tags: java, double

When doing:

```
double a = 1000000000 / FPS;
```

It gives me the warning:

*Integer division in floating point context.*

How can I solve this?

Comment: What warning? Please provide a full [mre]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two options. Add .0 at the end as such:

```
double a = 1000000000.0 / FPS;
```

or adding d at the end.

```
double a = 1000000000d / FPS;
```

Comment: Maybe add why this works so the OP understands. Otherwise Good answer

Comment: It says he is a new contributor and this seems like a relatively simple idea. I believe he is a beginner. I know what it's like to be a beginner and to be bombed with complicated ideas. I want to make it simple for him :). if I thought the circumstance were to be different then I would definitely do that!

Comment: Not an F; add a D. F forces float. floats are almost entirely useless. You want doubles.

Comment: There is a third option, probaby more depending on what `FPS` is. You must explain why this works.

Answer (score 25):

The warning occurs because you divide two integers `1000000000` and `FPS`, and the variable you want to assign the result to is `double`, a floating point type.

What you want instead is having a **floating point division**.
For this, one of the operands of the division has to be a floating point type.

You can do it in the following ways:

```
1000000000.0 / FPS; // make operand a floating point type (double)
1000000000.0f / FPS; //(float)
1000000000d / FPS; //(double)
(double)1000000000 / FPS; // cast operand to a floating point type (may be necessary if your operand is a variable)
```

and of course you can make `FPS` just a floating point variable instead of a integer variable.

Comment: the suffix `d` makes it a double already. adding a trailing zero doesnt make a difference

Comment: It doesn't say that in your answer. Casting it to `float` won't work, as the value is out of range.

Comment: I don't know what compiler you use, but casting to `float` works, even if the value is out of range https://javap.yawk.at/#tpUGn7

Answer (score 2):

to get rid of this warning use a helper variable
you have

```
double a = 1000000000 / FPS;
```

it become

```
double b =1000000000;
double a = b / FPS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if you are using a variable like this -

```
int totalPresentStudentCount,count;
(totalPresentStudentCount/count) * 100.00
```

Then simply add **1.0** with any of the doubles like that -

```
int totalPresentStudentCount,count;
(totalPresentStudentCount*1.0/count) * 100.00
```

Answer (score -3):

double a = 1000000000.00 / FPS; It is true.